# Redirect 100+ domains to single site subdirectories

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, referer

I have a few hundred domains spread over different registrars.
For ease of management, I set the name servers for all of them to a single service like above.com (they let you redirect anywhere)

I also have setup a wordpress site on shared hosting (linux) where each domain features some content, following this URL structure:

```
http://example.com/domain1
http://example.com/domain2
http://example.com/domain300
```

Now i´d like to accomplish that when someone types in browser, or is following a link:

```
http:// domain1.com -> should be redirected to http://example.com/domain1
http:// domain2.com -> should be redirected to http://example.com/domain2
http:// domain300.com -> should be redirected to http://example.com/domain300
```

Is there a way to avoid having to edit hundreds of domains/dns entries individually?

It would be nice if masking is possible:

If someone types in `http://domain1.com` he should be redirected to `http:// example.com/domain1` but the browser bar URL still shows `http://domain1.com`

I´m good at designing sites, but have very very poor coding ability.
Any templates or ready made solutions for that?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

What about slightly different route:

if wordpress URL structure will be setup like:

```
site.com/domain1.de
site.com/domain2.us 
..
site.com/domain300.com
```

Is it then easier to just point every domain to site.com, and have some rule to direct the traffic based on referrer to the matching subdirectory/URL structure?

```
domain1.de -> gets redirected to site.com/domain1.de
domain2.us -> gets redirected to site.com/domain2.us
..
domain300.com -> gets redirected to site.com/domain300.com
```

---

UPDATE:

I now have added following code to the .htaccess in the wordpress root directory:

```
# BEGIN Stackexchange hack 

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(domain[\d]+\..*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/%1 [L,R,QSA]
</IfModule>

# END Stackexchange hack
```

I can´t get it to work.. redirected domains will all go to index = example.com
instead being redirected to example.com/domain.de

Comment: Most decent DNS management services would offer an API or SDK that would allow you to create a simple one-off script to batch update all 300 DNS entries. If not then you can have `domain1` point to a specific IP and everything else point to `domain1` so a change in domain1 will propagate and you would only need to do this once (even if it is a huge pain)

Comment: Yeah thanks. I try to avoid anything complicated (don´t want to mess up...for me that is even a batch script). I updated/edited the original question slightly. Maybe with such url structure a easier solution is possible.

Comment: Updated original question with suggested solution. But can´t get it working.

Comment: change `[\d]+` to `[\d]*` to indicate that the number after `domain` is optional. Right now it expects `domainNNN.ext`

Comment: Ohh.. maybe i was not clear enough on the redirected domains. There is no number. domain1, domain2 could stand for really any domain name with any extension (a-z, 0-1) (com, net, org, de..) -> it´s just a bunch of different domains that could come in any shape and extension.

Answer (score 1):

When you set up your vhost in (assuming) Apache add the following:

```
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias domain1.com domain2.com .... domain300.com
```

Set up each of the domains you own to point to `example.com`

Your `.htaccess` could be the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(domain[\d]+\..*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/%1 [L,R,QSA]
```

Will rewrite domainX.com to example.com/domainX

Hard redirects will need to be done because of the change in host.

You *could* try to trick people by doing things like `history.replaceState("domainX.com")` in JavaScript to change the browser bar, but anyone who opens the console can see through the rouse. This is because if it was possible to serve content from `malicioussite.com` while having people think it's coming from `example.com` it would be very very naughty.

Comment: Thank you very much! You are right about  tricky/naughty tactic. Not intended as domain -> would go to site/domain. But thanks for highlighting this!

Comment: Your solution would also work if i just point all domains to site.com? (no vhost etc..) as i would just redirect all domains via dns service to site.com

Comment: @user1769562 well, kind of. You still need to set up apache to know how to serve them. Otherwise you'll be getting the default "It works!" message, unless you've replaced that with your default site. In the latter case it should work.

Comment: Thanks again! Sorry to bother you again: If the URL structure is "exact match" like in the updated original question.. is it working with just your htaccess?

Comment: I've updated the .htaccess rule a but to include extension. Overall that's a regex which you can tune based on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

> If someone types in http:// domain1 .com
>   he should be redirected to http:// site .com/domain1
>   but the browser bar URL still shows http:// domain1 .com

That's imposible due to security purpouses, you only can "emulate" this by setting in domain1.com an iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://example.com/domain1" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

> http:// domain1 .com -> should be redirected to http:// site .com/domain1
>   http:// domain2 .com -> should be redirected to http:// site .com/domain2
>   ..
>   http:// domain300 .com -> should be redirected to http:// site .com/domain300

The only way I know to do this is by setting up in each domain a 301 redirection to http:// site .com/domainX

Comment: Thanks for highlighting this! I just posted it as above.com (and others) offering masked URL forwarding. I now better understand the concerns